# Cant get Vector3.right to work with transform.Rotate in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, rotation

I am trying to make my camera rotate right around the gameobject it is assigned to. So far I can get it to rotate around the gameobject, but it is rotating left not right. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CameraRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
float time = 5.0f;
public bool updateOn = true;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(updateOff());
}

void Update()
{
    if (updateOn == true)
    {
        if (time >= 0)
        {
            time -= Time.deltaTime;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
}
IEnumerator updateOff()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10.0f);
    updateOn = false;
}
}
```

Comment: You mean you want the object to turn anti-clockwise instead of clockwise? Why don't you simply call `transform.Rotate(0, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);`?

Comment: ah. I am new to C#. I was trying to do                                        
transform.Rotate(-0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

Comment: well `-0` = `0` ;)

Comment: Yeah. Thank you so much. Now My intro animation is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    float time = 5.0f;
    public bool updateOn = true;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(updateOff());
}

void Update()
{
    if (updateOn == true)
    {
        if (time >= 0)
        {
            time -= Time.deltaTime;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
}
    IEnumerator updateOff()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10.0f);
        updateOn = false;
    }
}
```